# ::before não é exibida em <img>

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Criei uma espécie de *lazyload* (pré-carregamento de imagens) em JavaScript com o evento *scroll* onde algumas imagens só são carregadas quando elas entrarem na área visível da janela.

Para isso criei uma imagem genérica de 1x1 pixel transparente (`dt.png`) e coloquei no `src` das imagens e um atributo `data-src` com o caminho da respectiva imagem:

```
<img src="dt.png" data-src="img/foto1.jpg" class="lazyload">
<img src="dt.png" data-src="img/foto2.jpg" class="lazyload">
```

Ao fazer `scroll`, o código JavaScript irá verificar se a imagem está dentro do *viewport* da janela, se estiver irá substituir o valor de `src` por `data-src` carregando e exibindo a imagem. Até aqui tudo certo.

O problema é que gostaria que não ficasse uma área vazia no lugar da imagem, mas que houvesse nessa área um texto do tipo "Carregando imagem...", isso porque as vezes a imagem leva alguns segundos para ser carregada e dá a impressão que houve alguma falha. Enfim, gostaria que o usuário soubesse que ali será exibida a imagem.

Tentei fazer isso usando a pseudo-classe `::before` na tag `<img>` e até funciona se o `src` estiver vazio:

```css
.lazyload::before{
   content: 'Carregando imagem...';
   position: absolute;
   right: 3px;
   top: 3px;
}

div{
   width: 300px;
   background: red;
   padding: 15px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

img{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img src="" data-src="img/foto1.jpg" class="lazyload">
   <p>Texto qualquer</p>
</div>
```

> Mas com o `src` vazio não é interessante porque mostra o "ícone de
>   imagem partida" além de uma borda.

Agora com o PNG transparente, o texto do `::before` não aparece (mesmo o PNG sendo transparente):

```css
.lazyload::before{
   content: 'Carregando imagem...';
   position: absolute;
   right: 3px;
   top: 3px;
}

div{
   width: 300px;
   background: red;
   padding: 15px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

img{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk53m.png" data-src="img/foto1.jpg" class="lazyload">
   <p>Tem uma imagem transparante aqui em cima</p>
</div>
```

> Analisando na *inspeção de elementos* do navegador, notei que quando o
>   `src` está vazio ou com um caminho de imagem que não existe, o nó do
>   `::before` aparece, mas quando coloco um caminho de imagem correto, o
>   `::before` some.

Existe alguma forma de fazer esse `::before` ficar visível mesmo com o PNG transparente no `src` ou uma outra solução possível para esse caso usando CSS?

Comment: É interessante que neste [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JW2kH4spk0) esta técnica é usada e essa imagem cortada não aparece, talvez ela seja um comportamento default do browser que mudou. Uma ideia: e se você colocasse no src - ao invés do pixel transparente - um gif de ampulheta para o carregamento, o mesmo para todas as imagens, e depois mudasse o src - quando o scroll fosse feito - para a imagem correta?

Comment: Oi @Douglas. Eu pensei nisso também da ampulheta, mas as imagens são de tamanhos variados e não fica legal, vai ficar distorcida.

Comment: Bolei uma solução usando onload da imagem a ser carregada e um gif para o carregamento que fica centralizado na div que a imagem irá aprecer dentro, e some quando a imagem é carregada, veja no [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdh4pvzk/1/). O botão "carregar" simula a chamada a função que será chamada ao rolar a página. Não coloquei como resposta porque sua pergunta é mais sobre resolver com CSS e sobre esclarecer o comportamento do `::before`, mas acho que pode te ajudar de qualquer modo.

Comment: Se você decidir usar o onload em imagens, veja essa issue sobre [image.onload event and browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache), não estudei a fundo mas parece ser um problema sobre o onload não ser disparado se a imagem já estiver no cache do Browser. Não tive esse tipo de problema no exemplo que fiz no fiddle.

Comment: @Douglas é, eu acho que vou ter que usar jQuery nisso mesmo, até porque as imagens não possuem um contêiner próprio e não daria pra centralizar uma outra imagem exatamente na área da imagem principal. Tive pesquisando e realmente não dá pra usar pseudo-classes em tags <img>. A sua ideia é até funcional, mas eu tive uma ideia melhor onde eu não preciso mexer no HTML. Valeu pela força

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não faz sentido usar o pseudoelemento `::before` com `<img>`, pois essa tag não tem conteúdo (não tem tag de fechamento). Apesar do nome confuso, o [`::before` cria um pseudoelemento antes *do conteúdo*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content) do elemento especificado no seletor (ou seja, na posição de primeiro filho), e não antes do próprio elemento selecionado.

Em termos práticos, coloque o pseudoelemento num elemento externo à imagem.

Comment: É, vou fazer isso com JS mesmo. Obg!